# missing vtable error saying I have not defined my virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, g++, virtual-functions, vtable

I am having some issues getting a class to be instantiated, with an error telling me that I have not defined my virtual function in the class. I'm a little confused though, as I only have 1 virtual function (one function overall) and I have defined it. It's all inherited through a parent class Renderer.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "LifeSimulator.hpp"
#include "rlutil.h"
class Renderer
{
public:
    virtual void render(const LifeSimulator& simulation) = 0;
};
```

Next up on inheritance is RendererConsole.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "Renderer.hpp"

class RendererConsole : public Renderer
{
public:
    virtual void render(const LifeSimulator& simulation) override;
};
```

and then the definition in RendererConsole.cpp:

```
#include "LifeSimulator.hpp"
#include "RendererConsole.hpp"


void render(const LifeSimulator& simulation){
    rlutil::cls();
    rlutil::hidecursor();
    for (int i = 0; i<simulation.getSizeY(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < simulation.getSizeX(); j++) {
            if (simulation.getCell(i, j) == true) {
                rlutil::locate(i, j);
                rlutil::setColor(5);
                rlutil::setChar('*');
            }
        }
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }
    rlutil::showcursor();
}
```

The line where the error comes from in my main.cpp file is this

```
Renderer* renderer = new RendererConsole();
```

I'm sure the mistake is simple but I just can't seem to figure out what I did wrong. Thanks for any help.

Comment: In the definition `void render` -> `void RendererConsole::render`. Currently you have defined a free function, unrelated to the class.

Comment: One additional unrelated point: `virtual` in the derived class `RendererConsole` is redundant. You can simply write `void render(const LifeSimulator& simulation) override;`

Answer (score 1):

In RendererConsole.cpp: You need to specify that `render` belongs to `RendererConsole`

```
void RendererConsole::render(const LifeSimulator& simulation)
```

If you want to read a bit about it more you can check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Qualified_identifiers. The `::` is the so called scope resolution operator. It basically says that `render` can be found in the scope of (class) `RendererConsole`.